# Tomcat mapping URLs wrong

Tags: spring, tomcat, jenkins, tomcat8

I edited **context path** in TomCat server.xml, so that my webapps/app is displayed as root app instead of TomCat app on mysite.com (not mysite.com/app). In my app i have some .jsp files that are displayed correctly (mysite.com/main, /register) but some sites give me 404 error (mysite.com/home, /rxmsg, /signout).
Yet when i go to mysite.com/app/home, everything works perfectly

Every URL like this works perfectly in local (localhost:8080/home)

My git pushes are transfered to tomcat_home/webapps/ via jenkins

What causes some urls to 404?

Redirects are made by

```
return "redirect:main"; //URL is changing
```

or

```
return "main"; //URL not changing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem
In my tomcat server.xml changed

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

to

```
<Host name="mysite.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

and restarted my service.

BUT doing so, I cannot test my code on localhost now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create both Host tags and set localhost as the default host in the Engine tag:

```
<Engine defaultHost="localhost" ...
```

Comment: Aftter adding another Host tag, mysite.com works fine, but IntelliJ gives error 'Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
        javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=Server'